# Approximation polynomial fit to given data

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, polynomial-math, smoothing

I'm facing a problem with aproximation polynomial fit. A more detailed review of my problem is shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285811/smoothing-higher-order-polynomials-and-nonlinear-r-squared).
Basically I want to smooth the mid section of the polynomial that I got through long mathematical manipulation and is shown below.
[image]
The idea that I got is to take a range from the beginning and a range from the end of the polynomial (its points) and make an approximation polynomial that hasn't got the waving in the mid section; selected points are shown below.
[image]
However by using the `polyfit` function I didn't quite get the polynomial that I've hoped for.
[image]

This the crucial part of my code:

```
from sympy import*
import numpy as np
init_printing()
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S = np.linspace(25, 400, 1000)
SS = np.log10(S)
def f(logS): # the polynomial that I got
    return 10**(-57.2476193068601*logS**5 + 585.900632193053*logS**4 - 2384.35277925916*logS**3 + 4821.25582425353*logS**2 - 4845.47249368281*logS + 1943.75303313331)  

xdata = f(SS)
ydata = S

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi= 600, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.loglog(xdata, ydata,'k-')
# Data for new polynomial (approximation)
XX = xdata[:40].tolist()
X1 = xdata[len(xdata)-350:].tolist()
YY = ydata[:40].tolist()
Y1 = ydata[len(ydata)-350:].tolist()
for i in range(len(X1)):
    XX.append(X1[i])
    YY.append(Y1[i])

# Approximation polynomial fit
plt.loglog(XX,YY,'mo')
x_t = np.linspace(np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata),1000)
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(XX,YY, deg=5))

plt.loglog(x_t, p(x_t),'g-')
print(p)

plt.ylim((np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata)))
plt.xlim((np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata)*0.7))  

plt.xlabel('xdata')
plt.ylabel('ydata')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
```

I would like some advice on how to fix this approximation polynomial problem or if there is another way to solve the waving in the mid section - a better way of smoothing.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to increase the order of your polynomial?

Comment: I would like to use the same degree approximation polynomial as my original polynomial has. That is the idea of smoothing the mid section and compare their coefficients in the end...

Comment: It'll be difficult to find one polynomial to span your space and reproduce that data.  It's easy with piecewise polynomials.  I'd try that.

Comment: Is it possible to connect this polynomial pieces together so I keep the continuity? How could I implement this extra conditions regarding polynomial derivatives in their contacts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to fit a polynomial on regular data which is in exp-exp scale, and only plot it in log-log, where it looks like a polynomial. You will not be able to represent such relation with a polynomial. Preprocess everything to be in log scale in the first place, fit polynomial there, and if you want to go back to your exp-exp world, post-process again.

```
from sympy import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

S = np.linspace(25, 400, 1000)
SS = np.log10(S)
def f(logS): # the polynomial that I got
    return 10**(-57.2476193068601*logS**5 + 585.900632193053*logS**4 - 2384.35277925916*logS**3 + 4821.25582425353*logS**2 - 4845.47249368281*logS + 1943.75303313331)  



xdata = np.log(f(SS))
ydata = np.log(S)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10),facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'k-')
#plt.loglog(xdata, ydata,'k-')
# Data for new polynomial (approximation)
XX = xdata[:40].tolist()
X1 = xdata[len(xdata)-350:].tolist()
YY = ydata[:40].tolist()
Y1 = ydata[len(ydata)-350:].tolist()
for i in range(len(X1)):
    XX.append(X1[i])
    YY.append(Y1[i])


# Approximation polynomial fit
#plt.loglog(XX,YY,'mo')
x_t = np.linspace(np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata),1000)
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(XX,YY, deg=5))

#plt.loglog(x_t, p(x_t),'g-')
plt.plot(x_t, p(x_t),'g-')
print(p)

plt.ylim((np.min(ydata), np.max(ydata)))
plt.xlim((np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata)))  

plt.xlabel('xdata')
plt.ylabel('ydata')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a better way of smoothing a polynomial and solve this waving problem in general?

Comment: it depends on exact setting, existing constraints, what is the true, underlying goal and why. Fitting that you proposed is based on MSE, which might not be optimal. There are many possible smoothness criterions which one can use (especially if you can leave space of polynomials). One of the typical solutions would be some spline instead, to simply "stick" a part of a curve that you want to look differently. But as I said, in general the problem is underdefined now, and requires lots of assumptions to be something we can "solve" rather then "approach" :-)

Comment: I'm doing my MSc on this theme and through a mathematical procedure and experimental data I got extrapolated polynomials that would fit the best at all given experimental points. However, as you can see [HERE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FHDo5.png), higher grade polynomials (n=4, n=5) have this waving issue and I would like to get a continuous polynomials without any fluctuation. I don't know how to fix the original extrapolated polynomials, so I came to this idea here... but I would be glad if you could suggest me any literature or other sources that could be helpful on this matter. Thanks!